# Allocation memory for display

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to create a graphics library. I need to:

```
int NewDisplay(Display  **display, DisplayClass dispClass, int xRes, int yRes)
{

/* create a display:
  -- allocate memory for indicated class and resolution
  -- pass back pointer to Display object in display
*/
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

How can I allocate memory to class and to the resolution?

Comment: This question is unanswerable. Based on the comments, clearly you don't intend to allocate for the parameters dispClass, xRes, and yRes (let alone that they're not pointers-to-pointers). The only way to answer this question is to write the complete code that creates the display object, and we don't have nearly enough information for that.

Comment: It depends on the format of the display (is that the DisplayClass type?). Is it one byte per pixel or more?

Comment: the DisplayClass type is "typedef int DisplayClass"

Comment: Yes but what does the display class *mean*? This really smells like a "plz send teh codez" question.

Comment: This smells very much like a homework question, and I've tagged it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess:

```
int NewDisplay(Display  **display, DisplayClass dispClass, int xRes, int yRes)
{
    (*display) = new Display( dispClass, xRes, yRes );
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all the server side memory details,
http://brigitzblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/jspservlet-display-server-memory.html

Comment: No, I'm just saying "What" from here to infinity... since your answer is pointless.